# Android Timepicker garbled display

Tags: android, timepicker

I'm using a TimePicker in my activity. The hours wheel gets garbled when it is turned (see screenshot):

[image: Garbled Timepicker]

I'm testing this on a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.2

Here is my layout xml which is set as the content view on the activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
<TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/set_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it? Thanks